# Modify all PHP files within directory and subdirectories with Python

Tags: python, php, replace, directory, refactoring

I'm having issues scanning through a root directory and modifying all .php files that contain a certain reference. Essentially, we're looking to move our entire database. I have to find all records of certain tables and rename them appropriately. Here's the code I have so far:

```
import os
import re

directory = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/wsphp'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.php'):
            print(filename)
            open_file = open(filename, 'r')
            read_file = open_file.read()
            regex = re.compile('OLD DATABASE NAME')
            read_file = regex.sub('NEW DATABASE NAME', read_file)
            write_file = open(filename, 'w')
            write_file.write(read_file)
```

My code breaks when it attempts to open the file. The problem seems to be that 'filename' refers to JUST the filename without the entire directory ('index.php' rather than 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/wsphp/Subfolder/Subfolder2/index.php'). The root directory contains a few .php files as well as a bunch of subdirectories. Is there an easier way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, `filename` is just the filename. The path to the file is stored in `root`, so you need to do

```
open_file = open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r')
```